# HTML::FormHandler validate select

Tags: perl, validation, select, forms

I'm using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler) to create some forms, and I'd like to be able to validate any select fields on the form by making sure that whatever value submitted was actually a value given to the user. Right now this is how I have my select field set up:

```
has_field 'choice' => (
    type             => 'Select',
    label            => 'Choice',
    options          => [{value=>"1",label=>"One"},{value=>"2"=>label=>"Two"}],
    empty_select     => '---Choose an Option---',
    apply            => [{
                      check => ['1','2'],
                      message => 'Must be a value in the list.',
    }], 
);
```

Right now this works, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it? Since HTML::FormHandler already knows what options it has for the field, is there any way to just tell HTML::FormHandler to validate that the what the user choice is in fact one of those options? I've looked through the documentation and can't seem to find it anywhere, but it seems like something that would make sense to have for a field with predefined values. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without the `apply`? From https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler::Manual::Validation I got the feeling that this is just additional validation, but very basic stuff is built in. https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler::Field::Select on the other hand does not say anything about validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code for `HTML::FormHandler::Field::Select` this check is already done. Have you tried it?